# Monitorar o tempo de usuário no site

Tags: php, javascript

eu consigo monitorar quanto tempo um usuário fica conectado em uma página específica? Salvando no banco de dados o tempo que ele ficou.

A chefia aqui quer saber se os líderes estão usando um serviço de relatórios disponibilizados por nós, eu já monitoro a data e hora que eles acessam, tem alguma função em php ou javascript que faça isso? Não achei nada parecido

Comment: Você define algum tipo de `setInterval` a cada minuto você pode fazer uma requisição para o servidor, acrescentando em 1 minuto no backend. Não vai sobrecarregar seu servidor, pelo que eu estou vendo, se não eu recomendaria outra coisa.

Comment: você diz fazer um javascript fazendo um update a cada 1 minuto? Como eu pegaria o tempo? Ou simplesmente faria uma soma de 1 em 1?

Comment: a cada minuto o seu `setInterval` pode fazer uma chamada para seu servidor, tipo: `fetch('api.com/increaseTime')` a rota `increaseTime` vai pegar do banco, quantos minutos já tem guardado, somar com 1, e guardar.

Comment: você pode por um script de exemplo como resposta?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> você pode por um script de exemplo como resposta? – Ricardo Gonçalves

Faz um tempinho que não mexo com MySQL. Mas a query seria mais ou menos assim.

```
UPDATE table SET field = field + 1 WHERE id = {ID_DO_USUARIO}
```

No frontend é só passar o ID do usuário pro back

```
setInterval(() => {
  let id = user.id
  fetch(`http://api.com/increaseTime/${id}`)
    .then(res => res.json())
      .then(json => console.log(json))
}, 1000 * 60)
```

Comment: eu não consegui entender o teu código

Comment: Você não entendeu porque não teve contato com o `fetch` ?